# OpenCV: How to detect the position of label?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image below, how do I detect the label in the image, i.e. the line and label, but the most important thing is label, which is the label with numbering.

The image I'm trying to extract from is shown below

[image]

Here is my thoughts:

- Get all lines
- Rectangle out the label using contour
- And filter out some noise by finding label that is nearest to a line.

**Why my solutions didn't work?**

I have tried using HoughTransformP but it didn't work well.

Below is the example I have

[image]

The expected final result should be similar to this

[image]

Comment: Hi Tex, please elaborate what do you want to detect in the image. one thing which is clear is text. which line do you want to detect because the image also has regions which has curved lines

Comment: Hi @PrashantMaurya, I have updated the description. Thanks for asking the question.

Comment: Instead of using line detector for text/label, you can use certain object detectors like [east text detector](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/)  to detect text regions

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected final result, scene text detection and recognition algorithms will be very useful.

The following is a famous paper: [Detecting Text in Natural Scenes with
Stroke Width Transform](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/201020CVPR20TextDetection.pdf). In your case, you have an image that looks like a blueprint or engineering drawing. The situation is simpler compared to a natural scene. Also, in your case, all the text is facing the front without perspective distortion. It will be even more easy for the scene text detection algorithms.

In your case, you could run a recognition algorithm after the detection algorithm, to make sure you only capture the numbers.

Here is a well received project on github that you can experiment with: https://github.com/HCIILAB/Scene-Text-Recognition-Recommendations